# How can I typeset Julia code with the listings package?

Tags: listings, matlab, julia

I'd like to typeset some [Julia](http://julialang.org) code, syntax highlighting and all, with the `listings` package. For information, the [Julia language](http://julialang.org) is a strong contender for MATLAB, and is free and open-source.

However, [`listings` doesn't come with a language definition for Julia](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx). I've found a [Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net) specification for the language [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/71c0aa3e5660258af5c042058d5d8d3b82d93efb). How can I adapt it in order to properly highlight Julia code with the `listings` package?

For illustration purposes, here is an MWE with some a Julia code sample (adapted from http://julialang.org) embedded in an `lstlisting` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#= This is a code sample for the Julia language
(adapted from http://julialang.org) =#
function mandel(z)
    c = z
    maxiter = 80
    for n = 1:maxiter
        if abs(z) > 2
            return n-1
        end
        z = z^2 + c
    end
    return maxiter
end

function helloworld()
    println("Hello, World!") # Bye bye, MATLAB!
end

function randmatstat(t)
    n = 5
    v = zeros(t)
    w = zeros(t)
    for i = 1:t
        a = randn(n,n)
        b = randn(n,n)
        c = randn(n,n)
        d = randn(n,n)
        P = [a b c d]
        Q = [a b; c d]
        v[i] = trace((P.'*P)^4)
        w[i] = trace((Q.'*Q)^4)
    end
    std(v)/mean(v), std(w)/mean(w)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll find a `listings` language definition for the Julia language in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%%
%% Julia definition (c) 2014 Jubobs
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{Julia}%
  {morekeywords={abstract,break,case,catch,const,continue,do,else,elseif,%
      end,export,false,for,function,immutable,import,importall,if,in,%
      macro,module,otherwise,quote,return,switch,true,try,type,typealias,%
      using,while},%
   sensitive=true,%
   alsoother={$},%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morecomment=[n]{\#=}{=\#},%
   morestring=[s]{"}{"},%
   morestring=[m]{'}{'},%
}[keywords,comments,strings]%

\lstset{%
    language         = Julia,
    basicstyle       = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle     = \bfseries\color{blue},
    stringstyle      = \color{magenta},
    commentstyle     = \color{ForestGreen},
    showstringspaces = false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#= This is a code sample for the Julia language
(adapted from http://julialang.org) =#
function mandel(z)
    c = z
    maxiter = 80
    for n = 1:maxiter
        if abs(z) > 2
            return n-1
        end
        z = z^2 + c
    end
    return maxiter
end

function helloworld()
    println("Hello, World!") # Bye bye, MATLAB!
end

function randmatstat(t)
    n = 5
    v = zeros(t)
    w = zeros(t)
    for i = 1:t
        a = randn(n,n)
        b = randn(n,n)
        c = randn(n,n)
        d = randn(n,n)
        P = [a b c d]
        Q = [a b; c d]
        v[i] = trace((P.'*P)^4)
        w[i] = trace((Q.'*Q)^4)
    end
    std(v)/mean(v), std(w)/mean(w)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "begin" should be included in the keywords.

Answer (score 18):

For those of you coming from google and having found this page:

Inspired by Jubobs three year old post I have recently created a julia language definition for the listings package that tries to display julia code the same way as in the official online documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/

So if you are intrested, go and check it out: https://github.com/wg030/jlcode

Comment: Great! Have you asked the author of `listings` if he wants to include the language definition directly into the code or is it intended that it is separate?