# How can I typeset PowerShell code with the listings package?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm currently creating my diploma thesis, and used PowerShell to do some of the described work. I'd like to also put some of this code into the thesis and would therefore like to have syntax highlighting.

I've found several predefined languages defined in the `listings` package (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf)

Unfortunately PowerShell is not present. I'm wondering whether there is any package or "listings-powershell.prf" file available... Is there?

In case there is, could you please post the link? Otherwise, I will use `\lstset` and customize the listing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: You're right, `listings` doesn't come with a definition for PowerShell. Because I'm no PowerShell user,  I can't define a `listings` language for it myself, but I invite you to visit [this](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) and search for "bash, csh, and sh". That will lead you to the `listings` definitions for those three shells, which you can adapt for PowerShell; just make sure to use the user macro `\lstdefinelanguage` instead of the internal macro `lst@definelanguage`.

Comment: Give it your best shot. If you run into trouble and get stuck somewhere, you can always edit your question to make it more specific. People here will be happy to help you along. And once you're happy with the result, I encourage you to submit the language definition to the maintainer of `listings`,  so it can be included in a future release of that package.

Comment: It is probably because no-one have ever made a language setting for it (for highlighting). So you may have to write your own language specification for Powershell. You can see examples in `lstlang1.sty`, `lstlang2.sty` and `lstlang3.sty`

Comment: You may find [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212793/how-can-i-typeset-julia-code-with-the-listings-package/212794#212794) useful for defining a Powershell language for `listings`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Is there a way to embed a RegEx into the definition of the language? So that everything that matches the RegEx is highlighted. That would make the definition more robust for updates.. Otherwise I need to hard code all the current commands that have to be highlighted..

Comment: @sternze Unfortunately, no. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/can-the-listings-package-highlight-by-regexp

Comment: Have you found a solution? Would you share your powershell definition?

Answer (score 2):

Someone wrote the language specification for PowerShell.
Have a look here:
https://github.com/rmainer/latex-listings-powershell/blob/master/src/latex-listings-powershell.tex

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.