# How can I display julia output in latex?

Tags: listings, julia

I've been able to typeset julia code using listings package as mentioned in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212793/how-can-i-typeset-julia-code-with-the-listings-package).

But I also wanted to display Julia output in my latex document, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`minted`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package.  It does syntax highlighting with the [`pygments`](https://pygments.org) Python library, which happens to support Julia.

Additionally, Julia interactive output is supported through the `jlcon` lexer. It's not listed on the main site's language list, but it *is* listed on `pygmentize -L`.

Comment: This offers a good solution to print julia console output, but is there a way to highlight julia output from a jupyter ipython notebook as well ?

Comment: You mean highlighting an interactive Julia session?  Actually, [yes you can](http://pygments.org/demo/474338/).  The lexer you want is named `jlcon`.

Comment: dead link above (code sample).

Comment: @ja72 Thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix that right now.