# Complete setup for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX in VSCode with Julia Code using Minted

Tags: xetex, minted, julia

I've asked the Julia community [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/comprehensive-setup-for-including-unicode-julia-code-in-latex-document/26553/2?u=kapple) my question, and have gotten some nice help.

I thought I might cast a wider net for clarification.

TL; DR: What is the complete setup for VSCode to run XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, with working examples using unicode characters with minted? I've looked everywhere, finding the `latex-workshop.latex.tools` in one spot, the `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` in another spot, then example `.tex` files elsewhere, and they don't play nicely together. I am so confused.

So, I am new to the world of programming and spend more than half my time lost trying to understand what on earth everyone is talking about.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422090/141582) answer to a Stack Exchange question, Brad gives an example without the need to "define" new unicode characters (as with another answer to that question) because it has a huge variety of them.

In [this](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/209) post, the creator of LaTeX-Workshop discourages the use of the magic comment which is used in the Stack Exchange answer aforementioned, so I've deleted it. I also have no idea where the `latex-workshop.latex.toolchain` is meant to be copied-and-pasted (or edited).

I've learned from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290494/141582) that `minted` is better than `listings` because the former takes in the syntax highlighting and formatting rules from `pygmentize`, which I have installed through the python installer.

I've obtained an example of defining the `xelatex` tool from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56109129/9053825). But it has no example of a recipe.

[This](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/typesetting-julia-code-in-latex-documents-unicode/10176) guy's example isn't specific enough for me, i.e. VSCode settings are unclear to me.

The guy who [replied](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/comprehensive-setup-for-including-unicode-julia-code-in-latex-document/26553/2?u=kapple) to me in the Julia discourse community showed that the compilation works in Overleaf. I took his suggestion and tried compiling via the command line, but it doesn't work either.

The `JuliaProgramming.tex` file I have is as follows,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{minted}

\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\begin{document}

\section{Example Code}
Hello, here is some code.

\begin{minted}{julia}
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum # Although `sum` may be just as good in the code.
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

With the following as my `settings.json` file for VSCode.

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": "latexmk"
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape",
                "-xelatex",
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Are these sufficient for a successful run? It doesn't run successfully for me.

Edit: The output I get from running my `.tex` file is very lengthy. Some of the lines are/include (and repeat many times):

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "FreeMono" cannot be found.

`BI' can't be a subfont created by hbf2gf

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\<Path>\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
```

I could check the log file. I could try to install the font FreeMono. But I’ve been exploring rabbit holes for too long and I’m tired of it now.

Comment: The example works fine for me once I install the required font (`FreeMono`). The `latexmk` settings look sensible, but I have never used VSCode, so I can't tell you if they'll really do what they are supposed to. If things go wrong there should be a `.log` file that tells you about the errors, what does it say? Can you include the relevant bits in the question and upload the whole `.log` to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, please?

Comment: What has happened for you compiling on the command line? Which errors have been thrown? The example given should work there…

Comment: I get a lot of output. And I mean a lot. I'll edit my question to add some of the lines of output that seem most significant.

Comment: The shown bit of the `.log` file unfortunately only lets on that XeLaTeX doesn't find FreeMono. Have you made sure that the font is installed on your machine? Apparently it is sometimes safer to load a font by file name (`\setmonofont{FreeMono.otf}`) rather than by font name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure you have `FreeMono` installed on you machine. On GNU/Linux, you can check it by typing `fc-list`
2. Include `\usepackage{polyglossia}` on your preamble, click [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/typesetting-julia-code-in-latex-documents-unicode/10176) for more info.
3. Be sure you are using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmonofont{FreeMono} %switched to FreeMono

\begin{document}

\section{Example Code}
Hello, here is some code.

\begin{minted}{julia}
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum # Although `sum` may be just as good in the code.
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ I think long term is better to run through LuaTeX, you can skip the xunicode package. Also you do not need the polyglossia package. Did I miss something?